# How to pass dynamic parameters to a Sitecore page via the URI?

Tags: routing

On our website we have a page which is accessible via a path like:

> www.example.com/statistics

We would like this page to show different content based on the URI, e.g.

> www.example.com/statistics/**january**
>
> www.example.com/statistics/**february**

How can I implement this? If the parameters were static I could set-up Redirects, but in this case they are fully dynamic.

I also need to keep the URI after the user loads the page, so it cannot change back to **/statistics** during loading.

Comment: Do you mean Sitecore will have page /Home/Statistics. But January, February, etc. are not pages and will serve content dynamically?

Comment: @YogeshPatel correct. The 'Statistics' page will change based on the parameter.

Comment: As mentioned in slack, i think Wildcard is what you are looking for. https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/getting_to_know_sitecore/posts/wildcards-and-data-driven-urls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Sitecore Wildcard item. For that, create an item with name of * inside /Home/Statistics item (**/sitecore/content/Home/statistics/***). Remember, the * item (wildcard item) should not have any sibling. And, assign required presentation details to the item to show relevant statistics.

Now, when you request the page e.g. http://example.com/statistics/january, you will get the page context, and based on the parameter (january/fabruary, etc.) you can use your renderings to change content accordingly.

Read more on - http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/wildcard-items-pages-with-mvc-passing-the-correct-datasources-based-on-requested-item-url

Comment: Hm... After quickly trying it out it seems that this won't work for longer paths like /*/*/*/*/*? E.g. if I want to open /statistics/january/10/12/21/44

Comment: For longer paths, you can create hierarchy of wildcard items. The hierarchy of wildcard items must be more than or equal number of parameters.

Like, 
/statistics/Jan/01 needs /statistics/*/*
/statistics/Jan/01/am needs /statistics/*/*/* and so on